# How to append two Pandas DataFrames in a Specific manner

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Hi I have two Dataframes

[df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZqCV.png)

[df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTmMU.png)

Finally I want the Output df3

[df3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXIIL.png)

Can anyone please guide me how to do this in python?

Comment: Could you first fix the formatting of your question? It is not easily readable

Answer (score 1):

you want to do row-wise concatenation on common cols. use the pd.concat method. then sort by Sec and Date.

```py
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)
df3 = df3.sort_values(['Sec', 'Date'], ascending=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True, sort=True)
```